# How to display data in website created in Angularjs , data retrieved from SQL Server to Node.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sql-server-2012

My company uses SQL Server. I want to develop reporting dashboard for it, and I want to develop it using Nodejs + Angularjs.

I have this following code; can you give me a small example of

1. Retrieve data from SQL Server
2. Display in html page using Angularjs
3. Use Node.js for the serverside program.

I have a piece of code. which is not working.

```
//server.js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/website'));

require('./app/routes.js')(app);

var server = app.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('Server is running..');
});


//router.js
module.exports = function(app) {

// Load index file

app.get('*', function(req, res) {

   res.sendfile('./index.html'); // load the index from static files directory.

    var sql = require("mssql");

    // config for your database
        var config = {
        user: 'sa',
        password: 'sqlserver',
        server: 'FKHADER01',
        database: "master" 
            };

    // connect to your database
    sql.connect(config, function (err) {

         if (err) console.log(err);

         // create Request object
        var request = new sql.Request();

        // query to the database and get the records
        request.query('select count(*) CT from sales', function (err, recordset) {


            if (err) console.log(err);

            // send  records as a response
            res.send(recordset);
            var count = recordset[0].CT;

        });
    });



});};



//index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">    </script>
<body>

<div ng-app="" ng-init="count='5'">

<p>The name is <span ng-bind="count"></span></p>

</div>

</body>
   </html>
```

Please provide me any other best method , if you have

Answer (score 0):

```
I understand you are able to get the data from Sql server in your server.js Page. You would now want to send the data to the views.
So what you can do is use a view engine like EJS (npm install ejs) 
and app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
you can pass the data which you have in the "recordset" variable to 
the EJS page. The rendering would look something like 
res.render('./index.ejs',message:recordset , count :count)

You would also need to create an index.ejs file and copy all the 
context of index.html to it. The .ejs can simply be created 
by renaming index.html to index.ejs

In the index.ejs , inside script tags ,you can retrieve the 
recordset & count as 
<script>var rawQuery = <%message%>;  var  count = <%count%></script>  

You can then apply angular to manipulate the data in rawQuery,count
and attach it to the scope in the required controller. 


var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.count = count;
});

Hope this link helps.
https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application 
I understand you are able to get the data from Sql server in your server.js Page. You would now want to send the data to the views. So what you can do is use a view engine like EJS (npm install ejs) and app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); you can pass the data which you have in the "recordset" variable to the EJS page. The rendering would look something like

 res.render('./index.ejs',message:recordset , count :count)

You would also need to create an index.ejs file and copy all the context of index.html to it. The .ejs can simply be created by renaming index.html to index.ejs

In the index.ejs , inside script tags ,you can retrieve the recordset & count as

 <script>var rawQuery = <%message%>;  var  count = <%count%></script>

You can then apply angular to manipulate the data in rawQuery,count and attach it to the scope in the required controller.

 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.count = count;
});
Hope this link helps. https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application
```